# why do i have the python error unindent does not match any outer indentation level error

Tags: python, ubuntu

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi 
import time 
import os
import random 

api = TikTokApi()

def getLikeCount():
    tiktoks = api.byUsername('user', count=1)
    for tiktok in tiktoks:
        likeCount = tiktok["stats"]["diggCount"]
        shareCount = tiktok["stats"]["shareCount"]
        commentCount = tiktok["stats"]["commentcount"]
        followCount = tiktok["authorStats"]["followerCount"]
        return (likeCount,shareCount,commentCount,followCount)

def fag():
    os.system("afplay -/desktop/tiktok/fag.mp3 ")


def update():
    initLikeCount = 0
    while True:
        results = getLikeCount()
        currentNumLikes = results[0]
        print("sleep time")
        time.sleep(5)

        if currentNumLikes > initLikeCount:
            newLikes = currentNumLikes - initLikeCount
            initLikeCount = currentNumLikes
            print("new like count = ",newLikes)
            for x in range(newLikes):
                print("now playing this Fag.mp3",x)
                time.sleep(random.randint(0,3))
                fag()
           else()
            print("no new likes ):")
update()
#getLikeCount()
```

why is this happening i am making a tiktok bot that every time i get a like i get a noise to play (btw i am on ubuntu but this also happened with windows)

Comment: Because your `else` is indented differently than the `if`? Unless you completely butchered your code indentation while creating this question

Answer (score 0):

The `else` statement is not aligned with the `if` statement.

Btw, next time use ctrl-K to align your code within StackOverflow.

Comment: how tho i change the code to every thing i know and it still gives me the error

Comment: I still see that the `else`  is  just before the `if` aligned. It should be EXACTLY under the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of little errors in your functions `getLikeCount` and `update`

```
def getLikeCount():
    tiktoks = api.byUsername('user', count=1)
    for tiktok in tiktoks:
        likeCount = tiktok["stats"]["diggCount"]
        shareCount = tiktok["stats"]["shareCount"]
        commentCount = tiktok["stats"]["commentcount"]
        followCount = tiktok["authorStats"]["followerCount"]
    return (likeCount,shareCount,commentCount,followCount) # indentation corrected

def update():
    initLikeCount = 0
    while True:
        results = getLikeCount()
        currentNumLikes = results[0]
        print("sleep time")
        time.sleep(5)

        if currentNumLikes > initLikeCount:
            newLikes = currentNumLikes - initLikeCount
            initLikeCount = currentNumLikes
            print("new like count = ",newLikes)
            for x in range(newLikes):
                print("now playing this Fag.mp3",x)
                time.sleep(random.randint(0,3))
                fag()
        #  else() <- your code
        else: # indentation, brackets and colon corrected
            print("no new likes ):")
```